# Can not compile GQLViewer 2.5.2 with QT 5.3

Tags: qt5, qglviewer

I am on a Windows machine and trying to compile the [QGLViewer](http://www.libqglviewer.com)  with Qt 5.3. Therefore I use the GQLViewer.pro file to compile the lib with the Qt Creator. Unfortunately it always prompts:

> \libQGLViewer-2.5.2\QGLViewer\saveSnapshot.cpp:545: Error: operands to ?: have different types 'QFileDialog::Option' and 'QFlag' overwrite?QFileDialog::DontConfirmOverwrite:QFlag(0));

Anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in the QGLViewer library.
Upgrading to a version >= 2.53 should fix it.

2.53 changelog:

> Fix QFlag error with recent compilers in saveSnapshot.cpp (thanks xiaoyi).